# A way to unverify a GitHub commit

Tags: git, github, certificate, commit, git-commit

Every time I commit using GitHub's web interface, my commit gets marked as "Verified". Is there a way I can prevent the verify tag from being displayed (yes, I DO need it)?

Comment: If anyone is interested in context: our uni has banned us from using GitHub's online interface. Thus, every time I use the website to commit a change in my repo for home assignments, the "verified" tag instantly gives me away

Comment: I would assume the reason for your school not allowing you to use the web interface, is because they have an interest in you actually learning to use git. Why would you not want that, and try to avoid being detected? Git is more or less the industry standard of version control systems, there is no reason _not_ learning using git.

Comment: @AndreasLouv there's a big difference between maintaining and actually exercising a right ;)... but you're right, the question is (mostly) driven by curiosity

Comment: Even if you can get unverified commits somehow. The *committer* ist still GitHub as can be seen with `git log --format=full`. So it is still possible to know whether you used the web interface or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since GitHub [commit signature verification](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification) uses a [GPG key added to your profile](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/adding-a-new-gpg-key-to-your-github-account), the first step would be to remove that key.

At least new (and possibly older) commits won't be displayed as verified then.

---

If this is about **[GitHub itself signing commits](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/173494)**, with, as commented, [`0x4AEE18F83AFDEB23`](https://pgp.surf.nl/pks/lookup?search=0x4AEE18F83AFDEB23&fingerprint=on&op=index), you would need to not use GitHub directly, but push your commits.